# Сравнения значений в массиве

Tags: массивы, php

Добрый день, подскажите возможно-ли сравнить значения ключей?

> [test1] => Array ( [total] => 416 )
> [test3] => Array ( [total] => 497 )
>
> [test4] => Array ( [total] => 418 )
> [test1] => Array ( [total] => 45 )

В данной функции ?

```
function key_compare_func($key1, $key2)
{
    if ($key1 == $key2)
        return 0;
    else if ($key1 > $key2)
        return 1;
    else
        return -1;
}
var_dump(array_intersect_ukey($array1, $array2, 'key_compare_func'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну как бы...ты чего ждешь в ответ? Что мы на локалке будем пробовать? Ну неужто так сложно просто взять и попробовать самому? Или в гугл забить `array_intersect_ukey`? Ведь там первая ссылка-ответ на твой вопрос!

Ладно, поругался и хватит. Вот ответ на твой вопрос, это рабочий пример (из `php manual` по `array_intersect_ukey`)

```
<?php
function key_compare_func($key1, $key2)
{
    if ($key1 == $key2)
        return 0;
    else if ($key1 > $key2)
        return 1;
    else
        return -1;
}

$array1 = array('blue'  => 1, 'red'  => 2, 'green'  => 3, 'purple' => 4);
$array2 = array('green' => 5, 'blue' => 6, 'yellow' => 7, 'cyan'   => 8);

var_dump(array_intersect_ukey($array1, $array2, 'key_compare_func'));
?>
```

Comment: Дык он сравнивает ключи, а мне нужно что бы он еще и сравнивал значения ключей  [test4] => Array ( [total] => 418 )  именно total

Comment: мануал смотрел

Comment: в php есть модуль сравнения строк. что насчет тестинга руками?

Comment: спс, но уже нашел решение.

Comment: и какое же?

Comment: загнал в один массив под разными ключами, а там уже в цикле сравню